# Structure alignment not as expected

Tags: c, struct, alignment, structure

I have a structure

```
struct abc{
int32_t status;
union A;
};
```

sizeof(int32_t)     is  4.
sizeof(union A) is 24.

I was expecting that `status` should get aligned and take total 8 bytes (considering 64 bit compiler) but the size of structure abc is coming as 28 and not 32. Can someone explain why ? Note it is not pragma packed.

```
union A{
int8_t a;
struct b;
struct c;
}

struct b
{
int8_t a;
int32_t b2;
int32_t b3;
int32_t b4;
}

struct c
{
struct b;
int32_t c1;
int32_t c2;
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `structure`?

Comment: @dbush updated the question. Please check

Comment: A 64 bit compiler does not necessarily imply 64 bit alignment.

Comment: so can it be 4 bytes aligned too ? How do I check that ?

Comment: When you say "`sizeof(structure A) is 24`", are you talking about *`union A`*?  What is this `status` that you suppose should consume 8 bytes?  The member of `struct abc`?  Why would an `int32_t` occupy other than exactly 32 bits? The size of what is surprising you by being 28 bytes instead of 32?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I thought that the alignment is compiler dependent and it will be 8 but as the answer explained it can even be lesser than that.

Comment: @nielsen can you point me to the reference ?

Comment: Alignment *is* compiler-dependent.  And datatype dependent.  But that does not change the fact that some of the specifics of your question (still) don't make sense.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I edited the question, does that make sense now?

Comment: It's still a bit muddled, but I can work out what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @JohnBollinger can you point me to a good reference which tells more about "Alignment is compiler-dependent. And datatype dependent"

Comment: @CoolCamel, the definitive reference is section 6.2.8 of the C language specification.  The official spec itself is not available for free, but [this late draft](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) is almost identical.  Be warned, however: that document is very technical.  On the other hand, I can summarize in simpler terms: alignment is compiler dependent and datatype dependent.

Comment: On modern compilers you can use `_Alignof` to learn the alignment requirements of any type on that system. Works just like `sizeof`. When applying it to your structs/union on gcc x86_64 I get alignment of 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The largest field in any substructure is 4 bytes in size, so the structures will have 4 byte alignment.

Going from the bottom up, the largest field in `struct b` is a `int32_t`, so `struct b` has 4 byte alignment.

`struct c` contains `int32_t` which is 4 bytes and `struct b` which has 4 byte alignment, so `struct c` has 4 byte alignment.

`union A` has a `uint8_t` which has 1 byte alignment, `struct b` which has 4 byte alignment, and `struct c` which has 4 byte alignment, so `union A` has 4 byte alignment.

Finally, `struct abc` has a `int32_t` which is 4 bytes and `union A` which has 4 byte alignment, so `struct abc` has 4 byte alignment.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have one more doubt if one of my substructures contain a pointer int8_t* and it's a 64 bit compiler what will be the alignment of the structure ?

Comment: @CoolCamel If `sizeof(int8_t *)` is 8 then any structure containing it will have at least 8 byte alignment.

Comment: can you point me to a reference that says alignment is dependent on the alignment of elements in substructure ? Would be really helpful to see some examples etc.

Comment: @CoolCamel There's no hard rule on it, just a general way of operating.  See [the lost art of structure packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) for details.

Comment: @CoolCamel See also this question and answer where dbush is more precise regarding the C standard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662791/are-there-any-guarantees-about-c-struct-packing