# conversion to non-scalar type

Tags: c, struct, casting

This line will compile fine:

```
memcpy(&rp.iplow, &((struct sockaddr_in*) &dstl)->sin_addr, 4);
```

whereas what I originally coined it as:

```
memcpy(&rp.iplow, &((struct sockaddr_in) dstl).sin_addr, 4);
```

will say `error: conversion to non-scalar type requested`

Shall I conclude that one cannot use struct types for casting whatsoever?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting one C structure into another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995940/casting-one-c-structure-into-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are able to conclude that structure types are not able to cast directly. So you must need to type cast it as shown in first line written by you.