# How to achieve polymorphism in Python C API?

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I'm writing [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) object alternative, that accumulates arguments until their number become sufficient to make a call.

I use C API and I have `tp_call` implementation which when its called, returns modified version of self or `PyObject*`.

At first I followed [Defining New Types](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html) guide and then realized, that I just can't return different types (`PyObject *` and `MyObject*`) from `tp_call` implementation. 
Then I tried to not use `struct` with `MyObject*` definition and use `PyObject_SetAttrString` in `tp_init` instead, just like we do that in Python. But in that case I got `AttributeError`, because you can't set arbitrary attributes on `object` instances in Python.

What I need here is to make my `tp_call` implementation polymorphic, and make it able to return either `MyObject` which is subclass of `PyObject`, or `PyObject` type itself.

What is the sane way to do that?

### UPDATE #0

That's the code:

```
static PyObject *Curry_call(Curry *self, PyObject *args, 
                            PyObject *kwargs) {
    PyObject * old_args = self->args;
    self->args = PySequence_Concat(self->args, args);
    Py_DECREF(old_args);
    if (self->kwargs == NULL && kwargs != NULL) {
        self->kwargs = kwargs;
        Py_INCREF(self->kwargs);
    } else if (self->kwargs != NULL && kwargs != NULL) {
        PyDict_Merge(self->kwargs, kwargs, 1);
    }

    if ((PyObject_Size(self->args) +
         (self->kwargs != NULL ? PyObject_Size(self->kwargs) : 0)) >=
        self->num_args) {
        return PyObject_Call(self->fn, self->args, self->kwargs);
    } else {
        return (PyObject *)self;
    }
}
```

### UPDATE #1

Why I initially abandoned this implementation - because I get segfault with it on subsequent calls of partial object. I thought that It happens because of casting `Curry *` to `PyObject*` issues. But now I have fixed the segfault by adding `Py_INCREF(self);` before return `(PyObject *)self;`. Very strange to me. Should I really INCREF self if I return it by C API ownership rules?

Comment: How can `MyObject` be a subclass of `PyObject`? There are no classes in C

Comment: @ValentinLorentz: PyObject and its environment mimick polymorphism by including the "mother" struct into each "daughter" struct. Quite clever, and quite common in C. Read a bit of linux kernel, and you'll find that pattern here and there.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz In C API there is [the pattern of defining custom types](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html#the-basics), so a type defined in such way becomes a subclass of `PyObject` semantically, but not in C level of course. So I'm searching for the way to operate `MyObject` in a polymorphic way in C.

Comment: To see an example of what @MarcusMüller suggested, take a look at this, focusing on how a struct instance is embedded in another struct and the usage of `container_of` macro: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/rbtree.txt?v=3.18

Comment: @holgac: would you mind proofreading my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29575910/4433386)?

Answer (score 2):

If you've defined your `MyObject` type correctly, you should be able to simply cast your `MyObject *` to a `PyObject *` and return that. The first member of a `MyObject` is a `PyObject`, and C lets you cast a pointer to a struct to a pointer to the struct's first member and vice versa. I believe the feature exists specifically to allow things like this.

Comment: I like your answer even more than I like mine :) so [have an upvote](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/ca/ca211d0239f0cfe1e5a4cf3194a73db792e1eafe821967f4f73eeb4a1da4ee08.jpg)

Comment: People say, that [such casting can cause undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3995987/1818608)

Comment: @GillBates: They say that in situations where this specific exception does not apply. In the question you link, neither CMAcceleration nor Vector3d has an object of the other type as its first member.

Comment: @GillBates: But that's how scripting language interpreters in C work :D

Comment: Note, that `tp_call` should be able to receive that casted object as a first argument.

Comment: @GillBates: And it can. `tp_call` takes a `PyObject *` as its first argument, and if it was called correctly, you can cast that pointer to a `MyObject *` and proceed to interact with it as you would with any other `MyObject *`.

Comment: @user2357112 The problem is that I get segfault on subsequent call of my partial object. During first call, execution goes to my `tp_call`, then it accumulates arguments and returns `PyObject*`, but in second call, execution goes to `PyObject`'s `tp_call` and that causes segfault.

Comment: @GillBates: You most likely have an entirely unrelated bug.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, you right, and my previous statement is completely wrong. Segfault disappears when I add `Py_INCREF(self);` before `return (PyObject *)self;`. Very strange to me. Should I really INCREF `self` if I return it by C API ownership rules?

Comment: @GillBates: You should.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know your whole code, but as long as `MyObject` is a `PyObject` (compatible, i.e. has the same "header" fields, make sure you have a length field), CPython is designed to just take your MyObject as a PyObject; simply cast the pointer to PyObject before returning it.

As you can see here, that is one of the things that is convenient when using C++: You can *actually* have subclasses with type safety, and you don't have to worry about someone just copying over half of your subclass' instance, for example.

**EDIT:** because it was asked "isn't this unsafe": **yes**. It is. But its only as unsafe as type handling in user code gets; CPython lets you do this, because it stores and checks the `PyTypeObject *ob_type` member of the `PyObject` struct contained. That's about as safe as for example C++'s runtime type checking is -- but it's implemented by python developers as opposed to GCC/clang/MSVC/icc/... developers.

Comment: Wouldn't cast from `MyObject*` to `PyObject*` and than again to `MyObject*` cause undefined behavior?

Comment: not really, since a struct in C is really just the concatenation of its fields in memory, so it's safe to cast a pointer to a struct to a pointer to its first element; since that needs to be a unique thing, the opposite is true, too. The "type" safety gets emulated by using  `PyTypeObject *ob_type`.

Comment: *since a struct in C is really just the concatenation of its fields in memory* but if you cast bigger struct to smaller, it lets compiler think that, freed memory from bigger struct is available and it can start using it for something else, doesn't it?

Comment: no. the compiler doesn't take part in the freeing at all. When you free something, your runtime/OS looks into a table of allocated memory and says "ah right, there's an entry that someone allocated X bytes at that address, let's remove that entry". There is no runtime type safety in C.

Comment: I don't know about python-c api, but as you said, if both structs are compatible, casting should work fine (if python api wants to work with PyObject). But embedding `PyObject` in `MyObject` might be a choice too. Have a PyObject field in MyObject, and send it to python api. then when you receive a PyObject from python api, if you're sure it's MyObject, convert it to MyObject using a `container_of` macro. This way, the PyObject field in MyObject can be anywhere, not necessarily at the top.