# Upcasting and downcasting inherited structures in C

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I'm wondering if presented example is safe(no UB) in C:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t a;
} parent_t;

typedef struct {
    parent_t parent;
    uint32_t b;
} child_t;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t x;
} unrelated_t;

void test_function(parent_t* pParent) {
    ((child_t*)pParent)->b = 5U; // downcast is valid only if relation chain is valid
}

int main()
{
    child_t child;
    unrelated_t ub;
    test_function((parent_t*)&child); // valid upcast?
    test_function((parent_t*)&ub); // probably UB?

    return 0;
}
```

Due to an explicit cast there is no warranty and good typechecking but as long as proper parameters are passed this should work right?

Comment: *"...this should work."* What is supposed to work? If you mean is the relative position of `child` and `ub` in memory guaranteed – no.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think they're asking if `parent` is guaranteed to be at offset 0 whithin `child`, and whether the pointer casts in both directions are valid.

Comment: @akimata when you say "should work" what is intended to happen? Please show the expected result with an output. What does "inherit, upcasting and downcasting" mean in C?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Exactly what i was asking for, if i can safely cast up and down within a child. Ub is just an example where compiler won't moan but the behavior is pretty sure undefined and i'm not sure if there is a cleaner/safer solution to catch such mistakes.

Comment: Are you aware of `union`s?

Comment: Related: [Cast struct pointer to another struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757117/cast-struct-pointer-to-another-struct) with this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757117/cast-struct-pointer-to-another-struct#comment90478488_51758304).

Comment: @WeatherVane Not fully, as there is no downcasting mentioned, only upcasting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51762793/9072753 should answer your question. `downcasting mentioned, only upcasting` it does not matter (?)

Comment: As already mentioned, the answer you guys are proposing mentions upcasting which is fine but i need a confirmation that downcasting (casting from base to derived one).

Comment: C does not define nor distinguish _upcast_ nor _downcast_.  What OP has here, C calls _casting_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule *for casting* is [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7) :

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

Also in case of structures [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p15](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p15) :

> A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

And then *accessing* [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7) :

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
> expression that has one of the following types:88)
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a
>   member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

---

> as long as proper parameters are passed this should work right?

There is a vast ocean between "should work" and "is guaranteed to work". The goal is to write code that is guaranteed to work as intended – it has no undefined behavior, because there is no guarantee what happens when it's undefined.

> ```
> test_function((parent_t*)&child); // valid upcast?
> ```

Yes, it's defined behavior. `&child` points to `&child.parent`, so the resulting pointer has to be properly aligned to `parent_t`.

Then `(child_t*)pParent` is also valid, because it points to a `child_t` object.

Then accessing it `((child_t*)pParent)->` is also valid, because there is a `child_t` object accessed with the same type `child_t` as it is, so it's a compatible type for sure.

> ```
> test_function((parent_t*)&ub); // probably UB?
> ```

Most probably, *casting a pointer* from `unrelated_t*` to `parent_t*` is completely fine – most probably `alingof(unrelated_t)` is equal to `alingof(parent_t)`, because there are only `uint32_t` inside. But, it depends. It may be not valid, when the resulting pointer of `(parent_t*)&ub` is not properly aligned to `parent_t`.

After that, a similar story with `(child_t*)pParent` with the same pointer value inside `test_function`. Note that `child_t` may have stricter alignment requirements from `parent_t`, so while the previous cast may be valid, this one may be not, in the same fashion – depends on alignment requirements of types involved.

Then *after that, accessing* the value with `((child_t*)pParent)->` is undefined behavior. Accessing a pointer to `unrelated_t` object via `child_t *` handle is undefined behavior. `child_t` is not a compatible type with `unrelated_t`.

Comment: Alright, so it is safe to upcast and downcast structure pointers if they're related to each other like parent_t and child_t.

Comment: It's really unrelated... I wanted to convey the information: it's safe to do any cast as long as alignment is ok. You can do `(uint16_t*)&ub`. It's safe to _access_ data with compatible handle only. In this case, a pointer to the structure points to it's initial member, so both accesses are fine.

Comment: @KamilCuk, why is the "alignment is ok" sufficient for a cast to be safe? The safety of `test_function((parent_t*)&child);` follows from your quotations from the standard, but it only mentions alignment in the pointer _conversion_; as for _dereferencing_ a pointer, it requires that the types are compatible, doesn't it?

Comment: `why is the "alignment is ok" sufficient for a cast to be safe?` becuase `it only mentions alignment in the pointer conversion`, so the cast, i.e. pointer conversion, is safe when alignment is ok. I do not understand. `as for dereferencing a pointer...?` yes.